# Should investigators take Set Aside Cultists when playing with the Epidemic prelude?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-under-the-pyramids

When playing with [Epidemic](https://eldritchhorror.fandom.com/wiki/Epidemic) prelude

> After resolving setup, if Abhoth is the Ancient One, each Investigator spawns 1 Cultist Monster on a Wilderness space that does not contain a Cultist Monster.

and an Ancient One have Set Aside Cultist Monsters should these be drawn from

- the Set Aside Cultists?
- the monster cup?
- first the monster cup if able, then the Set Aside cultists?
- first the Set Aside cultists if able, then the monster cup?

Answer (score 1):

Draw from the set aside *Cultists* only.

[Rule Reference, Page 10](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/39/c1/39c182c1-6b0d-46c4-b5eb-dd6886b4c798/eh01_reference_guide1.pdf)

> Components that are set aside cannot be used except by effects that specifically name them. For example, a Monster token that has been set aside cannot be spawned except by an effect that specifically names that token.

By that - if you have set aside *Cultists*, you can not randomly or purposely draw a *Cultist* from the monster pile even if you have more cultists in the available pool. If you draw a cultist randomly from the pool, it should be discarded and another monster draw in it's place (if you haven't removed all *Cultists* from the pool.

Component Limits - the Core and Under the Pyramids sets have a limit of 8 cultists (5 core, 3 UtP). If you play with only the UtP expansion you would be removing all of the cultists. It can be inferred from this that the intention is that all cultists are removed from the general pool and only drawn from the set aside. In general when you set aside a monster the game specifies the maximum amount available but Cultists are prevalent in other expansions and this is not clearly dealt with in the rules.

Thematically when you set aside a monster it has a specific role, method or story around how they're coming into the world so it makes sense you would not encounter them randomly or in other ways.

Comment: Where did you find "if you have set aside Cultists, you can not randomly or purposely draw a Cultist from the monster pile even if you have more cultists in the available pool."? 
I was only able to find "Monsters cannot be spawned from the Monster cup if the Monster cup is empty. Set aside Monsters cannot be spawned if all set aside Monsters of the named type are on the game board.".
The "Set Aside" section in the reference guide doesn't say that when setting a Monster aside then other Monsters of the named type should be returned to the game box.

Comment: The quote is directly from the rules reference. The rest is my inference based on that rule.

In general when you set aside a monster you are removing all of those monsters from the pool. Expansions have added additional tokens of the same types which has clouded the rule a bit but look at it this way.

The core game comes with 5 cultists.
The UtP expansion adds 3 cultists.

If you play the core game with only the UtP expansion there are ONLY 8 cultists available, therefore you would ONLY be able to draw from the Set Aside cultists.